# How to correcttly initialize this double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm taking a course on C and I'm having a lot of trouble initializing a double pointer. I have made my best effort to reduce the practical exercise to this code where the error can be reproduced:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _tCoordinateNode
{
    struct _tCoordinateNode *next;
} tCoordinateNode;

typedef struct _tDateTimeNode
{
    int a;
    tCoordinateNode *coordinatesList;
    struct _tDateTimeNode *next;
} tDateTimeNode;

typedef struct _ApiData
{
    tDateTimeNode *timeNodeList;
} tApiData;

void dateTimeNode_insert(tDateTimeNode **_list)
{
    if ((*_list) == NULL)
    {
        (*_list) = (tDateTimeNode *)malloc(sizeof(tDateTimeNode));
        (*_list)->a = 1;
        (*_list)->coordinatesList = NULL;
        (*_list)->next = NULL;
    }
}

tDateTimeNode *api_getTemporalData(tApiData *data)
{
    return data->timeNodeList;
}

int main()
{
    tApiData data;
    data.timeNodeList = NULL;

    dateTimeNode_insert(&(api_getTemporalData(&data)));
    printf("%d", data.timeNodeList->a);
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault error, but I cannot see why. Any idea what's causing the error? I suppose it should work and the variable should be set to 1.

Comment: Are you sure you ran this exact code to get the seg fault? Doesn't look like it will cause that. There are other problems with this code but please first confirm whether the seg fault can be reproduced with this exact code.

Comment: Em, yeah, I have run this code with the command gcc -o t test.c && ./t and I'm getting a segmentation fault error on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I did not get a segfault, that was because of some prints I had. I'm going to add them again.

Comment: The `a` member is an `int`. You do not print `int` values by using `printf(timeNode->a)`. The first argument to `printf` must be a format string that tells it what to output, including conversions from other arguments to decimal (such as `%d` from `int`), hexadecimal, and so on.

Comment: After adding the format string I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: In addition to the `printf` problem you need to know that `timeNode` is a *copy* of the `data.timeNodeList;` value. Changing `timeNode` does not change `data.timeNodeList;`. Just do basic debugging - print out the two pointer values or examine them in a debugger.

Comment: @kaylum oh I see, is there a way to change that? Like not make it a copy?

Comment: Why have `timeNode` at all? Just pass in `&(date.timeNodeList)`. If you really must then it needs to be `tDateTimeNode **timeNode = &(data.timeNodeList); dateTimeNode_insert(timeNode);`

Comment: You can make things a lot easier on yourself if you create a separate struct representing the list: `struct _tCoordinateList { struct _tCoordinateNode *head; };`, and similarly a `struct _tTimeList`.

Comment: @kaylum I thought about that but I'm getting: lvalue required as unary '&' operand. Please see updated answer to reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, you didn't do what was suggested. You did something different. You are still returning a *copy* of the pointer value. And it is illegal to get the address of a return value which is what the error msg tells you. You need to return `&(data->timeNodeList)`

Comment: I think the new error is because I'm creating a pointer to a temporal value (the return of a function). But I store the result of the function in a variable, then we come back to the first problem.

Comment: @kaylum am I still returning a copy? Sorry I thought that returning a pointer did not copy it.

Comment: It doesn't copy the thing it points to. But it does copy the value of the pointer - that is, the address. You are basically returning a number which is the same value as the original pointer but is not the original pointer itself.

Comment: `&(api_getTemporalData(&data))` is not valid C, you cannot get a segfault with this code because you cannot run it at all, it will not compile.